# MacLaurin 6th degree higher error bound value of a function not explicitly given

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is all the information we're given:
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x) &= 2^{-1} f(x)\:\text{ for all }x\\
f(0) &= 1\\
|f(x)| &\le 6\:\text{ for all }x\in [-3, 3]
\end{align}
$$
How would one go about finding the higher error bound of the approximation of $f(2)$ with $T_6(2)$, namely the 6th degree MacLaurin equation?

The solutions say that the correct answer is $5/7$! btw.

Comment: The third piece of data, $\;|f(x)|\le 6\;$ for all $\;x\in[-3,3]\;$ is pretty strange to me...the solution fo the differential equation is pretty simple and we get $\;f(x)=\pm e^{x/2}\;$, with the sign depending of whether $\;x<0\;\;or\;\;x\ge 0\;$. And apparently you want to approximate the value of $\;f(x)\;$ with a Maclaurin polynomial, right?

Comment: How did they come up with 5/7! as being the upper limit of the error bound (Rn)?

Comment: No, I want to find the error of the approximation (the R(n))

Comment: The $\;7!\;$ is pretty straightforward, but that $\;5\;$ is weird imo...I get $\;3\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

$$f'=\frac12f\iff\frac{f'}f=\frac12\iff\log|f|=\frac12x+C\implies |f|=Ke^{x/2}$$

and since $\;1=f(0)=K\implies f(x)=\pm e^{x/2}\;$, and from here: the residue (error) for $\;T_6\;$ is

$$\left|\frac{e^{c/2}x^7}{2^77!}\right|\le\frac{e^{x/2}\cdot2^7}{2^77!}\le \frac{e^{2/2}}{7!}\le\frac3{7!}$$

I can't see where they got that $\;5\;$ in the numerator from...although I suppose you could argue that it is certainly trivially true that $\;3/7!\le 5/7!\;$ ...

Comment: If you instead use $e^{c/2}\le e^{3/2}<5$ for all $c\in[-3,3]$, the interval in the given information, you get the provided answer, so I would presume it is a typo.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, I know...

Answer (score 0):

First note that

$$f^{(6)}(x)=\frac{\mathrm d^5}{\mathrm dx^5}f'(x)=\frac12f^{(5)}(x)=\dots=\frac1{2^6}f(x)$$

And by Lagrange remainders we know that:

$$|f(x)-T_6(x)|\le\frac{|x|^7}{7!}\max_{\xi\in[-3,3]}|f^{(7)}(\xi)|=\frac{|x/2|^7}{7!}\max_{\xi\in[-3,3]}|f(\xi)|\le\frac{\color{red}6|x/2|^7}{7!}$$

for all $x\in[-3,3]$. Hence:

$$|f(2)-T_6(2)|\le\frac6{7!}$$

which isn't the desired bound, though close.

---

Seeing as it is easy to analytically solve for $f(x)=e^{x/2}$ here, one can furthermore see that

$$|f(x)|\le e^{3/2}<5\quad\forall x\in[-3,3]$$

and so I would presume the $6$ was a typo and it should be $5$ instead. Substituting $5$ in place of $6$ gives the desired bound:

$$|f(x)-T_6(x)|\le\frac{|x/2|^7}{7!}\max_{\xi\in[-3,3]}|f(\xi)|\le\frac{\color{red}5|x/2|^7}{7!}$$

$$|f(2)-T_6(2)|\le\frac5{7!}$$